# Move mouse cursor(OSX Version of windows' SetCursorPos)

Tags: c++, macos

I've been trying to mouse my mouse cursor on Mac OSX El capitan 10.11.2. I've done some digging and found many ways some were deprecated and some were new. Tried many examples but none of them worked so far.

Here's what i've tried so far

```
CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(CGPointMake(200, 200));
```

this didn't work and returned 0

```
CGPoint warpPoint = CGPointMake(42, 42);
CGWarpMouseCursorPosition(warpPoint);
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition(true);
```

CGWarp also returns 0 here(basically the same thing lel)

```
CGDisplayHideCursor (kCGNullDirectDisplay);
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition (false);
CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint (kCGDirectMainDisplay, CGPointMake(200, 200));
CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition (true);
CGDisplayShowCursor (kCGNullDirectDisplay);
```

This comes from apple.developer didn't work either.

IMPORTANT NOTE: i am working on a VMWare Virtual Machine.

I've tried a few more code pieces but nothing is working.

Comment: I would guess that the problem is that you're working on a virtual machine. Probably the guest OS is not allowed to move the host OS's cursor. `CGWarpMouseCursorPosition()` definitely works in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the event queue.  Here are some sample calls in Objective-C:

```
CGPoint startButton = CGPointMake(self.gameOrigin.x + 35, self.gameOrigin.y + 340);
CGEventRef click_down = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
                                                NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseDown,
                                                startButton,
                                                kCGMouseButtonLeft
                                                );
CGEventRef click_up = CGEventCreateMouseEvent(
                                              NULL, kCGEventLeftMouseUp,
                                              startButton,
                                              kCGMouseButtonLeft
                                              );
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, click_down);
CGEventPost(kCGHIDEventTap, click_up);
CFRelease(click_up);
CFRelease(click_down);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it didn't work either(i've tried an example like this.). Could it be because i work on a virtual machine ?

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference at all.  What does the `CGEventCreateMouseEvent` call do in your case?